# Different retry attempts for different exceptions in Spring @Retryable

Tags: spring, spring-retry

In my SpringBoot app I have a Client, which can send a POST request. And during POST it can have several exceptions.

I want to have a retry logic in case of 2 different exceptions. But in a way that the max-retry-attempts should take effect for each exception, and not together. Hard to explain, but an example:

The max-retry-attempts is configured for 3. If I get exception1 type, than retry, I have 2 retry left. Try again and get again exception1, then retry and now I have 1 retry left. Try again and now I get exception2, then try and now I have again 2 retry left, because the previous retries were for the exception1 but not for exception2. So exception2 retry has just started.

Is it possible? I tried with this, but this does not starts over the retry-attempts for different exception, if exception1 occured and then exception2 occured, then I had 1 retry left:

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 3, value = {Exception1.class, Exception2.class}, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 3000, multiplier = 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to create a custom retry policy; and configure it into a `RetryTemplate` and `RetryOperationsInterceptor`; use the `interceptor` property on the annotation to reference the interceptor.

Comment: do you have any example for this? because I could not find proper example with different exceptions to act as I described.

Comment: No; as I said, you would need to create a custom policy to add that logic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think something exists for the @Retryable annotation. If you choose to use RetryTemplate implementation, you can use the following to have different retry attempts for different exceptions and set it into the RetryTemplate object:

```
final SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicyTenTimes = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
simpleRetryPolicyTenTimes.setMaxAttempts(10);
final SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicyTwoTimes = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
simpleRetryPolicyTwoTimes.setMaxAttempts(2);
final Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, RetryPolicy> policyMap = new HashMap<>();
policyMap.put(RetryException.class, simpleRetryPolicyTenTimes);
policyMap.put(HardFailException.class, simpleRetryPolicyTwoTimes);
final ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy();
retryPolicy.setPolicyMap(policyMap);
return retryPolicy;
```

You can find the example here:
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.retry.policy.ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy